# Sql query inserts data in database twice

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I was updating the database fields using php and mysql when a duplicate row started to getting stored in the DB.
Doesn't work on localhost neither on the server
Here's the code :

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
mysqli_select_db($con,"excel");
$sql="INSERT INTO mark (date, time_stamp, agency, a_name, first_name, last_name, address, city, zip, phone, auto, ins_det)
VALUES ('$_POST[date]','$_POST[time]','$_POST[agency]','$_POST[a_name]','$_POST[f_name]','$_POST[l_name]','$_POST[add]','$_POST[city]','$_POST[zip]','$_POST[phone]','$_POST[auto]','$_POST[ins_det]')";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if (!$res)
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
    else
    {
        echo "1 record added";
    }
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Here's the code for webform which redirects to the above code when is submitted

```
<html>
    <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <h2 align='center'>Mark Noffsinger</h2>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="outer-container">
        <div class="col-sm-4"><form action="show_data.php">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Show this month's leads"/></form>
            </div>
        <form action="form_data.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal">

            <div class="col-sm-8" "form-group">
                <label>Date:</label><br>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" name="date"/>
                <label>Time:</label><br>
                <input type="time" class="form-control" id="time" name="time"/>
                <label>Agency:</label><br>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="agency" name="agency"/>
                <label>Agent's Name:</label><br>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="a_name" name="a_name"/>
                <label>First Name:</label><br>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="f_name" name="f_name"/>
                <label>Last Name:</label><br>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="l_name" name="l_name"/>
                <label>Address:</label><br>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="add" name="add"/>
                <label>City:</label><br>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city"/>
                <label>Zip:</label><br>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="zip" name="zip"/>
                <label>Phone:</label><br>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone"/>
                <label>Auto:</label><br>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="auto" name="auto"/>
                <label>Insurance Details:</label><br>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ins_det" name="ins_det"/><br>
                <input type="Submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>  
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

edit : Phone number is used as a primary key here and everytime i insert the data it is i think using cached info , tried clearing cache, used diff browsers but still everytime i submit the form it takes phone number of the last row updated and gives the error now for duplicating leads

Comment: Please be aware that your code is **vulnerable** to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). **Never** use `$_POST` directly in SQL statements! You should use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead, binding to variables. Also ensure that your database user only has the [**required privileges**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege). You can refer to [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) for further information on how to prevent SQL injection in PHP :)

Comment: None of this code would, by itself, create two rows - unless somehow you are executing the script twice? Perhaps there's a mistake in the front-end code, so it submits the form twice or something? The only other thing I can think is...in the question text you mention you were trying to **update** the fields, but the code here is doing an **insert** - i.e. always creating a new row, not changing existing rows. So it made me wonder if you misunderstood what the code is actually doing

Comment: And yes as Obsidian says, this code is currently a security disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: what i want is for this code to atleast run correctly in localhost
i don't know why it inserts same row twice i want a solution to this rest I'll update and do when this works correctly

Comment: Ok well as we've said the code above doesn't reproduce the issue on its own. Take another look at my first comment and see if any of that applies to your situation.

Comment: Minus the security problems, I'm going to suggest that this PHP file is accidentally being run twice. Please check that it is only been hit once.

Comment: Caching is not used for data being sent from browser to server, only for the opposite process. What is the exact error message you are seeing please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Other Stackoverflow Engineers has stated, your code is a security disaster if you plan to use it in production..

I just pick three form parameters**(first_name, last_name, address)** to recreate this code of yours while ensuring that sql injection 
attack is not possible.  You can addon other form parameters following my method.

**Please ensure that all database credentials are okay before testing**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","my_password","yourdb goes");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables Against sql injections
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['f_name']);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['l_name']);
$address = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['add']);

$sql="INSERT INTO mark (first_name, last_name, address)
VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$address')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: using a prepared statement would be the rather current method, which does not require explicitly escaping the input. once this was only possible with `PDO`, but meanwhile `mysqli` also supports it.

Comment: Error: Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY'
even after using ur code
where phone number is a primary key

Comment: How can you make phone number a primary key. I now understand that the issue is from your table index. You should an Id or something else a primary key. Your table should look something like create table mark(id int primary key auto_increment, first_name varchar(30),last_name varchar(30)); etc. and my code should work for you

Comment: Or you can try another phone number during inserting and it will work. Duplicate entry means that phone number is existing in the database. You can either delete it or insert new phone thatt is unique. My code will then work for you

Comment: yeah phone number once updated aren't updated again that's why I used it as a key 
and everytime i am using a different number still it uses last row's phone and give error as a duplicate

Comment: @ParakhShukla "still it uses last row's phone and give error as a duplicate". That's impossible. It can only use the value you submitted through $_POST. if you are sure the value didn't exist in any row before you submitted the form, then you must somehow be triggering the form twice. Do some more debugging/monitoring to ensure you aren't running the script twice somehow. P.S. I just noticed that in your original code you have put `$_POST[phone]` ...but this is wrong... `phone` is supposed to be a string, not a name of a constant. `$_POST["phone"]` is correct. Same for all your other fields.

Answer (score 0):

when you use `INSERT` it will most likely (attempt to) `INSERT` a new row ...

the correct verb would be `REPLACE INTO`, which is either `UPDATE` or `INSERT INTO`. this saves one prior `SELECT` statement, which would have to determine whether `UPDATE` or `INSERT INTO` has to be used; because what you are trying to do is adding a `UNIQUE` key twice, which is strictly illegal.

using `phone` as `PRIMARY KEY` might lead to issues. would rather suggest to use some `AUTOINCREMENT` `contact_id` column instead... simply because there are various ways how to format a phone number - and this is user input - further checking the input `$_POST` with `isset()` and `!empty()` is suggested; additional client-side data validation does not matter here. I also find the table-name `mark` strange, which probably should rather be normalized to a column `agent_id`.

see the documentation for [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), which are quite useful.